# Get day from array of dates via html form

Tags: php, foreach

I have a form which submits an array of fields e.g:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="schedule-date[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="schedule-start[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="schedule-end[]">
```

with php I am trying to get the day of the week from the date `foreach` so far I only get the last day. Here's my code.

```
$date = $_POST['schedule-date'];
foreach($date as $d){
$day = date("l", strtotime($d));
}
$start = $_POST['schedule-start'];
$end = $_POST['schedule-end'];

foreach( $date as $key => $n ) {
echo $date[$key]." ".$day." "$start." ".$end;
echo ;
}
```

I get:

- 2018-12-01 Sunday 9start 18end
- 2018-12-02 Sunday 10start 20end

In the above the sunday is being repeated. How can I get the correct days? e.g. Saturday and Sunday etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calculating the day for each date. You are using the already calculated day.

```
$date = $_POST['schedule-date'];

// rest of the code

foreach( $date as $key => $n ) {
  $day = date("l", strtotime($n)); // move this line inside for loop
  echo $date[$key]." ".$day." "$start." ".$end;
}
```